# Сall a specific code at a certain point in time in Android

Tags: java, android

Developing an Android application. I need to call a specific code at a certain point in time. But I have one problem - when the phone goes to sleep, the code is called late. I tried both AlarmMeneger and Firebase JobDispatcher, but I could not cope with this problem. What do i use? I can not solve this problem for three weeks

Comment: You can use `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this JobScheduler for that,

```
private JobInfo buildJobInfoForTask(Context context,
                                    long timeTillFutureEvent) {
    ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, SchedulerService.class);

    return new JobInfo.Builder(FUTURE_JOB_ID, serviceComponent)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE)
            .setOverrideDeadline(timeTillFutureEvent)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();
}
```